# How can I share code between multiple graphql ruby mutations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, graphql, graphql-ruby

I'd like to write a method that is used by multiple mutations, similar to defining a method in a controller that is shared amongst multiple actions. How can I do this?

Comment: Assuming that your mutations classes are subclasses of `Mutations::BaseMutation`,  have you considered defining the shared methods in `Mutations::BaseMutation` class?

Comment: That's interesting, thanks. One desire is to have the method have access to `ctx`, similar to how a controller method would have access to `params`